# ngx-bootstrap tooltip not working for Div

Tags: angular5, ngx-bootstrap

I am using angular 5 and ngx-bootstrap 2.0.5 version but I am not getting any tooltip inside component.

```
<div class="btn" alt="Ok to Call" tooltip="Calling" placement="bottom"></div>
```